# Partition recovered

Tags: partition, mbr, uuid

Partitions MBR has been destroyed accidentally by a friend, Then most partitions are unviewable which is too bad, can all the partitions be recovered? I have a text file including the original partitions range for each partition, and the type, UUID. I tried to use fdisk to delete all of partitions then created them by their range. Some times fdisk warned me the sector is in use, or do you want to remove the signatue? What should I choose, and what I should be carefull with? Alternate to `fdisk`?

Answer (score 0):

If the data inside the partitions are not deleted, them **testdisk** application certainly can recover your partions structure very well.

But you will probably need to reinstall and reconfigure grub.

A lot of live CDs can do all this, a good example with a ready-to-go **testdisk** (and much much more) can be found here: http://en.altlinux.org/Rescue

**Note:** If you are very sure and have a file as you say with the **real**, the **REAL** original positions just re-create the partitions in the same range without formating and just try to remount it after a reboot. All your data should be there.

Good lucky!

Comment: Does the re-creating partition with fdisk or testdisk? The fdisk will ask me some questions. Like 'the sector is in use', is that mean I have entered the wrong range?

Comment: No fdisk is probably saying that you already have a partition in the entered ranges that is already created, you just need to mount it. But if you think the partition fdisk is showing is wrong, you should delete it first.

Comment: `testdisk` is measured in cylinder while `fdisk` is sector, if the re-creation of partition is excuted by 'testdisk', how to convert cylinder from sector?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an alternative. [Testdisk and Photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

Don't fiddle around with your partition table. Make a full backup of your hdd and run Testdisk on your backup if you like your data.

Have a look at their [Partition Recovery forum](https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=5&sid=8313f396ac378b74287f7a0a426ea344).